# Do iPhones support UIPopoverView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a universal app. Will I be able to use the UIPopover View Controller universally (for both iPad and iPhone)?

Comment: I'm interested why is this questios has downvoted?!

Comment: @rmaddy. How do you know if there was "complete lack of effort to find my own answer"? There should be the option to down-vote comments for being presumptuous.

Comment: Since the answer is clearly given in the Overview section of the reference docs for `UIPopoverController`, since stackoverflow showed you some related questions giving the answer before you even submitted  your question, and since a few seconds with Google would have turned up countless answers, I think it is safe to say that there was no effort to find your own answer. I'll admit I could have worded my original comment better but it's still a valid point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  It is only supported on iPad.  There are third party widgets that emulate it, but the Apple one will throw an exception if you use it on iPhone.

From the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices.
>   Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.

See [CocoaControls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=popover) for some substitutes.

Comment: I've seen that in fb iPhone app. Isn't that the popover?

Comment: It's not a UIPopoverController.

Comment: I know. I was refering to "There are third party widgets that emulate it, but the Apple one will throw an exception if you use it on iPhone"

Comment: "it" refers in both cases to the UIPopoverController, not the third party widgets.

Answer (score 2):

As Aaron has already pointed out, UIPopoverView is available only for iPad,
I know from experience that if you implement your own without following the HIG, apple will reject your app, in my case my menu didn't have an arrow pointing to the element triggering it to appear.

[iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41)